# Error: "The 'MySQL Connector Net 6.4.4' package did not load correctly", en Visual Studio 2013 Community

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013, mysql-connect

Tengo instalado Visual Studio 2013 Community

Instalé MySQL para Visual Studio a partir de esté link:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=470092

Después, utilizando MySQL Installer 8.0.23 instalé Conector/NET 8.0.23 a partir de esté link:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/

[image: captura de instalación]

Más tarde cuando abro Visual Studio, aparece el siguiente error:

> The 'MySQL Connector Net 6.4.4' package did not load correctly.
>
> The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the
> installation of another extension. You can get more information by
> examining the file
>
> 'C:\Users\Man\AppData\Roaming\MicrosoftWisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml'.
>
> Restarting Visual Studio could help resolvethis issue.
>
> Continueto show this error message?
>
> Sí        No

El archivo contiene el siguiente código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ActivityLog.xsl"?>
<activity>
  <entry>
    <record>1</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.289</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 version: 12.0.40629.0</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>2</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.289</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Running in User Groups: Administrators Users</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>3</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.289</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Available Drive Space: C:\ drive has 183418372096 bytes; G:\ drive has 1602002944 bytes</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>4</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.293</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Internet Explorer Version: 11.0.9600.18860</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>5</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.294</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>.NET Framework Version: 4.0.40305.0</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>6</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.294</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>MSXML Version: 6.30.7601.18431</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>7</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.308</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>Microsoft Visual Studio Appid Stub</source>
    <description>Application launch on system with DPI X/Y: 96/96</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>8</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.491</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{00CD9DDA-7350-457C-A240-71BD667FC4DE}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>9</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.491</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Task Scheduler Package]</description>
    <guid>{00CD9DDA-7350-457C-A240-71BD667FC4DE}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>10</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.508</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>Package Framework</source>
    <description>Initialized ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider from SetSite.</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>11</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.514</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Task Scheduler Package]</description>
    <guid>{00CD9DDA-7350-457C-A240-71BD667FC4DE}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>12</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.537</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{5E56B3DB-7964-4588-8D49-D3523AB7BDB9}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>13</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.537</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Environment Package Window Management]</description>
    <guid>{5E56B3DB-7964-4588-8D49-D3523AB7BDB9}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>14</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.555</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Environment Package Window Management]</description>
    <guid>{5E56B3DB-7964-4588-8D49-D3523AB7BDB9}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>15</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.558</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{2DC9DAA9-7F2D-11D2-9BFC-00C04F9901D1}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>16</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.559</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Visual Studio Logging Package]</description>
    <guid>{2DC9DAA9-7F2D-11D2-9BFC-00C04F9901D1}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>17</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.559</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{2DC9DAA9-7F2D-11D2-9BFC-00C04F9901D1}</guid>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\Common7\IDE*\VsLogUI.dll</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>18</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.570</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Visual Studio Logging Package]</description>
    <guid>{2DC9DAA9-7F2D-11D2-9BFC-00C04F9901D1}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>19</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.737</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{F384B236-B4A9-401B-BC58-3106E3ACA3EC}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>20</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.737</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Shell Common UI Package]</description>
    <guid>{F384B236-B4A9-401B-BC58-3106E3ACA3EC}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>21</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.741</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Shell Common UI Package]</description>
    <guid>{F384B236-B4A9-401B-BC58-3106E3ACA3EC}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>22</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.791</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{8FF5C2A8-5EBA-4717-8EE1-46B6427D8FF3}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>23</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.791</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [MRU Package]</description>
    <guid>{8FF5C2A8-5EBA-4717-8EE1-46B6427D8FF3}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>24</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.792</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [MRU Package]</description>
    <guid>{8FF5C2A8-5EBA-4717-8EE1-46B6427D8FF3}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>25</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.960</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>26</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.960</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function LoadDTETypeLib</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>27</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.970</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Leaving function LoadDTETypeLib</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>28</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.970</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
    <guid>{80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>29</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.970</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>30</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.970</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
    <guid>{18BEB7F2-CA98-11D1-B6E7-00A0C90F2744}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>31</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.970</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>32</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.970</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
    <guid>{80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>33</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.971</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>34</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.971</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
    <guid>{80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>35</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.971</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{79A115C9-B133-4891-9E7B-242509DAD272}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>36</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:08.972</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [MySQL Connector Net 6.4.4]</description>
    <guid>{79A115C9-B133-4891-9E7B-242509DAD272}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>37</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:09.053</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [MySQL Connector Net 6.4.4]</description>
    <guid>{79A115C9-B133-4891-9E7B-242509DAD272}</guid>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DataDesign.Interfaces, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>38</record>
    <time>2021/04/16 22:37:09.054</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [MySQL Connector Net 6.4.4]</description>
    <guid>{79A115C9-B133-4891-9E7B-242509DAD272}</guid>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DataDesign.Interfaces, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
</activity>
```

He intentado reinstalar todo de diferentes formas pero hasta ahora nada ha funcionado, ¿alguna sugerencia?

Doy gracias de antemano a todos los que respondan.

Comment: ahi mismo te esta diciendo que no encuentra el archivo Microsoft.VisualStudio.DataDesign.Interfaces buscalo en el proyecto o en la computadora en la carpeta %WINDOWS% es una DLL y referenciala desde VS

Answer (score 0):

después de investigar por un largo tiempo encontré que Conector/NET es incompatible con Visual Visual Studio 2013 Community entonces instalé Visual Visual Studio 2015 Community y funcionó